# How to set up paths correctly for node, npm, and yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

When trying to create a new create react app project I get the following:

```
> npx create-react-app my-app
  node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  Error: Cannot find module 'has-flag'
```

Does my setup look right?

```
> which node
/Users/grant/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/node

> $echo $PATH
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/grant/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

> whereis npm
npm: /Users/grant/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/npm

> npm config get prefix
/usr/local

> yarn global list
yarn global v1.22.19
info "create-next-app@13.1.6" has binaries:
   - create-next-app
✨  Done in 2.30s.

> yarn global bin
/usr/local/bin
```

Node v18.13.0
npm v9.4.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with the `has-flag` module, which is a required dependency for `create-react-app`. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the `has-flag` module with the following command:

```bash
npm install has-flag@latest
```

After that, try creating the new React app again with the following command:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app
```

If it still doesn't work, you can try the following command:

```bash
npm install create-react-app -g
```

Then create a new React app with the following command:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: I get the following error npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity when running npm install create-react-app -g. But my etwork settings look correct. How to check network settings?

Comment: - Check the npm registry: You can run npm config get registry to see if the registry is set correctly. If it's not set correctly, you can set it to the default registry with the following command: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`.
- Clear the npm cache: You can clear the npm cache with the following command: `npm cache clean --force`.
If none of the above steps solve the issue, you can try re-installing node and npm

Comment: I have done all the suggestions already. Nothing worked. Thank you for trying to help.